# PostgreSQL write amplification

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to find how much stress PostgreSQL puts on disks and results are kind of discouraging so far. Please take a look on methodology, apparently I'm missing something or calculating numbers in a wrong way.

### Environment

PostgreSQL 9.6.0-1.pgdg16.04+1 is running inside a separate LXC container with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (kernel version 4.4.0-38-generic, ext4 filesystem on top of SSD), has only one client connection from which I run tests.

I disabled `autovacuum` to prevent unnecessary writes.
Calculation of written bytes is done by following command, I want to find total number of bytes written by all PostgreSQL processes (including WAL writer):

```
pgrep postgres | xargs -I {} cat /proc/{}/io | grep ^write_bytes | cut -d' ' -f2 | python -c "import sys; print sum(int(l) for l in sys.stdin)"
```

### Tests

With `#` sign I marked a database command, with `→` I marked result of write_bytes sum after the database command. The test case is simple: a table with just one `int4` column filled with 10000000 values.

Before every test I run set of commands to free disk space and prevent additional writes:

```
# DELETE FROM test_inserts;
# VACUUM FULL test_inserts;
# DROP TABLE test_inserts;
```

#### Test #1: Unlogged table

As documentation states, changes in `UNLOGGED` table are not written to WAL log, so it's a good point to start:

```
# CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE test_inserts (f1 INT);
→ 1526276096
# INSERT INTO test_inserts SELECT generate_series(1, 10000000);
→ 1902977024
```

The difference is **376700928 bytes** (~359MB), which sort of makes sense (ten millions of 4-byte integers + rows, pages and other costs), but still looks a bit too much, almost 10x of actual data size.

#### Test #2: Unlogged table with primary key

```
# CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE test_inserts (f1 INT PRIMARY KEY);
→ 2379882496
# INSERT INTO test_inserts SELECT generate_series(1, 10000000);
→ 2967339008
```

The difference is **587456512 bytes** (~560MB).

#### Test #3: regular table

```
# CREATE TABLE test_inserts (f1 INT);
→ 6460669952
# INSERT INTO test_inserts SELECT generate_series(1, 10000000);
→ 7603630080
```

There the difference is already **1142960128 bytes** (~1090MB).

#### Test #4: regular table with primary key

```
# CREATE TABLE test_inserts (f1 INT PRIMARY KEY);
→ 12740534272
# INSERT INTO test_inserts SELECT generate_series(1, 10000000);
→ 14895218688
```

Now the difference is **2154684416 bytes** (~2054MB) and after about 30 seconds additional 100MB were written.

For this test case I made a breakdown by processes:

```
                            Process                   | Bytes written
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/postgres                  |             0
 \_ postgres: 9.6/main: checkpointer process          |      99270656
 \_ postgres: 9.6/main: writer process                |      39133184
 \_ postgres: 9.6/main: wal writer process            |     186474496
 \_ postgres: 9.6/main: stats collector process       |             0
 \_ postgres: 9.6/main: postgres testdb [local] idle  |    1844658176
```

Any ideas, suggestions on how to measure values I'm looking for correctly? Maybe it's a kernel bug? Or PostgreSQL really does so many writes?

**Edit:** To double check what write_bytes means I wrote a simple [python script](https://gist.github.com/papulovskiy/e5b4009415adff305b44db3f02f127a4) that proved, that this value is the actual written bytes value.

**Edit 2:** For PostgreSQL 9.5 Test case #1 showed 362577920 bytes, test #4 showed 2141343744 bytes, so it's not about PG version.

**Edit 3:** [Richard Huxton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1029453/richard-huxton) mentioned [Database Page Layout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-page-layout.html) article and I'd like to elaborate: I agree with the storage cost, that includes 24 bytes of row header, 4 bytes of data itself and even 4 bytes for data alignment (8 bytes usually), which gives 32 bytes per row and with that amount of rows it's about 320MB per table and this is something I got with test #1.
I could assume that primary key in that case should be about the same size as data and it test #4 both, data and PK, would be written to WAL. That gives something like 360MB x 4 = 1.4GB, which is less than result I got.

Comment: Why are you not referencing https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-page-layout.html? I fail to see how any measurements make sense without some comment upon the page layout.

Comment: @RichardHuxton, because it did not help me to understand. I mentioned, that I accept page layout costs ("rows, pages and other costs", if I take something like 24 bytes of header, 4 bytes for data and 4 bytes for alignment, it's 32 bytes per row and 320m bytes per table), also, I'd accept a double value for PK, which consist of the same data, and duplication for WAL (if I can assume changes being logged the same way they written to the storage), that gives 360MBx4=1.4GB.